# Journey uses engagement split but number of opens are not getting captured accurately

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, analytics, email-tracking

I have a journey that sends an email and then wait for 10 days after which based on whether the contact has opened an email or not, it sends the follow-up email in the 'No' path. When I track the number of opens, I see 0 opens but at the same time I see 500+ clicks.

As my engagement split uses 'Opens' as the decisive factor, if the Opens are zero then all the contacts will receive follow-up emails.

I went through this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249050&type=1) and I haven't put tracking pixel code in my HTML paste email. I can't do it now because my journey is currently running, and the first email in which I should have put the tracking pixel code is already sent to contacts. Is there a way I can ensure that the number of Opens are accurately monitored in my journey and only non-openers receive the follow-up email. Thanks!

Comment: You can never accurately monitor opens. That should be something you should be aware of. First people with active AdBlocker will never show an open state, neither do people where you had to respect their wish to be not tracked (DoNotTrack Newsletter criteria). Furthermore many firewalls inspect emails and therefore open them. That said you cannot be sure if a person has open or not opened an email. And one extend: You can change an email within a running journey and put your tracking code inside of it and update the activity.

Comment: In that case, we cannot rely on Engagement Split, right? SFMC should specify this in their documentation because if anyone refers this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_the_engagement_split_activity.htm&type=5 and uses engagement split, they will almost never get expected results. According to me this is a major loophole in this functionality. They haven't even mentioned about tracking pixel in the above documentation, so if someone doesn't go through this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249050&type=1, they will end up getting inaccurate results.

Comment: AFAIK tracking pixels are inside the standard templates of salesforce. When you decide to create an own template you should be knowing what you do. tracking pixels and other functionalities are very easy to see when you edit a template. HTML editor -> </> Symbol -> and you find many of the system snippets of salesforce when you scroll down past your own.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't put the open tracking pixel in the email you cannot accurately monitor the opens of the past emails unfortunately.

If this is a feasible workaround for you, you could change the email activities that send the follow-up messages to filter out subscribers who have already clicked the first one, as they did definitely open it. This would work using an exclusion script, that checks the opens for the specific send. The easiest would be setting up an automation, that writes all subscriber keys of subscribers who clicked to a data extension. Then the exclusion script would check if the subscriber is on the data extension.

However, there are a few restrictions:

- This is no real open tracking as it isn't possible without the tracking pixel
- The contacts go through the "not opened" path and just the send is suppressed

**Further reading:**

- [Marketing Cloud - Exclusion script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/191285/36218)
- [Exclude Subscribers from a Triggered or User-Initiated Send in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213980&language=en_US&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can still [update the email if the Journey is currently running](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5). This was released in a recent rollout.

1. Hover over the email in the Journey canvas.
2. Click the blue button which says "View or Update Activity"
3. Click "View Email"
4. Click Edit Email
5. Add the open pixel: `<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">`
6. Click "Save and Exit"
7. Click "Summary"
8. Click "Done"